# Random Draw from Equal Numbers of Balls of 4 Colours: Probability of 2 of One Colour and 1 each of Two Other Colours

Tags: probability

A bag contains equal numbers of red, blue, green and yellow balls.  Four balls are drawn at random, *with replacement* after each ball is drawn.  One way to classify the possible outcomes is:

1. 4 balls of the same colour.
2. 3 balls of one colour and 1 of another.
3. 2 balls of one colour and 2 of another.
4. 2 balls of one colour, 1 of another, and 1 of yet another.
5. 4 balls, all of different colours.

What is the best way to find the probability of outcome 4?

I reasoned as follows. Altogether there are $4^4=256$ possibilities.  The 2 balls of one colour could be of any of the 4 colours. Considering the draws in order, those two balls could be drawn in $\binom{4}{2}=6$ ways. The first of the other balls could be any of the 3 remaining colours, and the second could be any of the 2 remaining colours.  The probability is therefore:

$$P(\text{outcome 4}) = \frac{4 \times 6 \times 3 \times 2}{256} = \frac{144}{256} = 0.5625$$

I wonder whether this is correct as it seems (to me at least) slightly counter-intuitive that the probability of just one of the 5 outcomes should be more than $0.5$.

Prompted by Ned's comment, my calculations of the number of possibilities falling into each of the patterns are respectively 4; 48; 36; 144; 24, which do sum to 256. But it still seems surprising that one pattern has so many more possibilities than any of the others.

Comment: It's not that counter intuitive considering the first outcome has only $4\over 256$ chance.

Comment: To verify it, compute how many of the 256 fall into each of the five patterns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some intuition, maybe, using conditional probability. After three draws, the only possibility that rules out the case (2,1,1) is three of the same color, which only happens 1/16 of the time, so 15/16 of the time, you have a chance of hitting (2,1,1) on the last draw.

With (2,1) on the first three, you have 50% chance of (2,1,1) and with (1,1,1) you have 75% chance of (2,1,1). So 15/16 of the time, you approach the last ball with at least 50% chance of getting (2,1,1).

Comment: So writing subscript $_4$ for events when drawing 4 balls and subscript $_3$ for events when drawing 3 balls, we have: $P(2,1,1) _4 = P[(2,1,1) _4 | (2,1) _3] + P[(2,1,1) _4 | (1,1,1) _3] = (0.5)(9/16) + (0.75)(6/16) = 9/32 + 9/32 = 0.5625$.  That makes it more intuitive.